# Difference between `scanf("%19[^\n]s",str);` and `scanf("%19[^\n]",str);`

Tags: c, scanf

This

```
  char str[20];
  scanf("%19[^\n]s",str);
  getchar(); // To remove the `\n`
  printf(str);
```

and

```
  char str[20];
  scanf("%19[^\n]",str);
  getchar(); // To remove the `\n`
  printf(str);
```

produce the same results. I know that `[^\n]` scans until it encounters a `\n`. But what I could not understand is that

- Are there any differences between the two `scanf`s?
- Isn't the `s` necessary in the second `scanf`?
- Which one should I be using to scan a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the input is

```
Line one
stuvwxyz
```

The first `scanf()` reads `"Line one"` into `str` and then fails to read an s;
The second `scanf()` reads `"Line one"` into `str` and doesn't fail.
In both cases, the input position is at the newline at the end of "Line one".

If the `scanf()` had a space in the conversion string to consume the newline (not necessarily a good idea)

```
scanf("%19[^\n] s", str);
scanf("%19[^\n] ", str);
```

and it was followed by another `scanf()`, the code with the first scanf would read in `"tuvwxyz"`; the code with the second would read `"stuvwxyz"`.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have written `"%19[^\n]"` you don't need the `%s` which indicates it is a string. 
It is already specified by the amount of characters (19) you want to read.

The statement:

```
 scanf("%19[^\n]s",str);
```

expects a string and then expects an `s` character.

To answer your question: Which one should I use?

Neither one. Use `fgets` for this specific input.

Answer (score 3):

This program will only read one input. As `%19[^\n]s` fails to read an 's'

```
#include<stdio.h>         
#include<stdlib.h>        

int main() {              
    char acText[20] = {""};
    char acTexts[20] = {""};
    scanf ( "%19[^\n]s %19[^\n]", acText, acTexts);
    printf ( "%s\n", acText);
    printf ( "%s\n", acTexts);
    return 0;
}
```

This program will read two inputs

```
#include<stdio.h>         
#include<stdlib.h>        

int main() {              
    char acText[20] = {""};
    char acTexts[20] = {""};
    scanf ( "%19[^\n] %19[^\n]", acText, acTexts);
    printf ( "%s\n", acText);
    printf ( "%s\n", acTexts);
    return 0;
}
```