# Input sanitisation in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name [20];
    char command [100];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%19[^\n]s", &name);
    sprintf(command, "echo Hello %s; echo The time is currently:; date", name);
    system(command);
}
```

This code was then modified to the following:

```
#define IS_VALID 1
#define NOT_VALID 0
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char name [20];
    char command [100];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%19[^\n]s", &name);
    if(validate(name) == IS_VALID) {
        sprintf(command, "echo Hello %s; echo The time is currently:;"
        "date", name);
        system(command);
    } else
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
}

int validate(char* input) {
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(input); i++)
        if(!isalpha(input[i]))
            return NOT_VALID;
    return IS_VALID;
}
```

Now what I need to do is modify the code again so that it is safe for use and prints the name input even if the user enters invalid characters for example if the user enters ;/etc/passwd this will be changed to etcpasswd or the invalid charcters get replaced by a - so it will be changed to --etc-passwd. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: please format your question.

Comment: @iharob **bold** done

Comment: I think you know what to do: "invalid charcters get replaced by a -". So what is the question?

Comment: yea I know thats what I need to do but I dont know how to do it @Drop

Comment: Then [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Drop well since this is the first time I've pretty much looked at C i'd say not a whole lot but I have however tried coming up with an IF condition but I don't know exactly what  to include in it.

Comment: `scanf("%19[^\n]", name);` the `s` and the `&` are errors. Even better than `scanf()` would be to use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> //for using isdigit()

int main() {
    char name [20];
    char command [100];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%19[^\n]", name); //explained below
    validate(name);
    sprintf(command, "echo Hello %s; echo The time is currently:; date", name);
    system(command);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void validate(char* input) {
    for(int i=0; i < strlen(input); i++)
        if(input[i] && !isalpha(input[i])) //if current character is not 0(NUL) and is not an alphabet
            input[i]='-'; //replace current character with a hyphen
}
```

And

```
scanf("%19[^\n]s", &name);
```

In all your examples should be

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", name);
```

The `&` is not required as the name of the array "decays" to a pointer to its first element(`char*`) and the `s` isn't a part of the `%[` format specifier. See [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/26571657/difference-between-scanf19-ns-str-and-scanf19-n-str)

Answer (score 0):

*I missed that you want the invalid chars replaced by hyphens. This code removes them.*

Add another char array declaration to your code like this:

`char cleanedCommand [100] = {0};`

Pass the address of the cleanedCommand array to your validation function:

```
if(validate(name,cleanedCommand) == IS_VALID) {
```

Change the declaration of the validate function to accept that new argument

```
int validate(char* input, char* output) {
```

Inside the validate function, add an else clause to your existing if statement, copying input[i] to output[i].

Change your sprintf() and system() calls to use cleanedCommand.